# Como retornar uma varável específica de dentro de uma function?

Tags: php, funções

Neste código eu dei um `return $array` e estou usando os dados dentro do `foreach`, até ai tudo bem.

Eu gostaria também de usar a variável `$url_controle` lá dentro do arquivo que eu chamei a função.

**Pergunta:** Como eu posso imprimir esta variável lá no outro arquivo? Dei um `return $url_controle` mas parece que não funcionou.

```
function list_all_pages() {

    $url_controle = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url_controle = explode('/', $url_controle);
    $url_controle = $url_controle[2];

    global $pdo;

    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM tb_paginas WHERE tipo = '$url_controle' ORDER BY ID DESC";
    $exc    = $pdo->query($sql);
    $cnt    = $exc->rowCount();
    $array  = $exc->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $array;

}

################
EM OUTRO ARQUIVO
################

$pages = list_all_pages();

foreach ($pages as $valores) {
    echo $valores['ID'];
    echo $valores['titulo'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um array de retorno com as informações desejadas, aí seu código ficaria assim:

```
    function list_all_pages() {

        $url_controle = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $url_controle = explode('/', $url_controle);
        $url_controle = $url_controle[2];

        global $pdo;

        $sql    = "SELECT * FROM tb_paginas WHERE tipo = '$url_controle' ORDER BY ID DESC";
        $exc    = $pdo->query($sql);
        $cnt    = $exc->rowCount();
        $array  = $exc->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $retorno = array("url_controle" => $url_controle, "pages" => $array);
        return $retorno;

}
```

### EM OUTRO ARQUIVO

```
$pages = list_all_pages();
echo $pages['url_controle']; //valor que vc deseja obter

foreach ($pages['pages'] as $valores) {
    echo $valores['ID'];
    echo $valores['titulo'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Todo o segredo da ***Solução para esta Pergunta*** está no `return` que deve enviar um `array` informando todas as variáveis que podem ser usadas.

No exemplo abaixo, vai observar que passei um array associativo que é recuperado no arquivo aonde a `function` é chamada.

```
function list_all_pages() {

    global $pdo;

    $url_controle = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url_controle = explode('/', $url_controle);
    $url_controle = $url_controle[2];

    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM tb_paginas WHERE tipo = '$url_controle' ORDER BY ID DESC";
    $exc    = $pdo->query($sql);
    $cnt    = $exc->rowCount();
    $array  = $exc->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Aqui eu monto um array associativo que envia várias informações
    // Neste caso estou enviando $array e $url_controle

    return array('array' => $array, 'url_controle' => $url_controle);

}

################
USO DA FUNCTION
################

// Aqui eu armazeno todo o conteúdo da function dentro da variável $conteudo
$conteudo     = list_all_pages();

// Aqui eu armazeno o $array (SQL) dentro da variável $dados
$dados        = $conteudo['array'];

// Aqui eu armazena uma variável de $controle que vem da function
$controle     = $conteudo['url_controle'];
```

Agora que já tem as informações armazenas em variáveis é só usa-las aonde achar conveniente conforme o tipo de cada uma delas.

Por exemplo, `$url_controle` é uma string enquanto `$array` é um array de dados para usar dentro de um `foreach` por exemplo.